# How to read csv-input using named groups in java?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm currently working on a program which takes input from a csv-file.
The structure of this input is well known. I want to read the file using regex. Though I know regex, I rarely use them and I guess I made some simple mistake(s)...

I created a stub of the code for you to.

The first two lines are my "real" demoinput and the corresponding regex, which does not work. Each line consists of a ID, a Name, a bool attribute (1 or 0) and a reference to the father-node.

Below that there are my "training" demoinput plus regex. I stripped away everything but the id.

The scanner never matches my `LINEPATTERN`. I guess there also will be problems with getting the group values...

Any help is appreciated

```
//  private final static String DEMOINPUT = "0,ROOT,1,null\n1,NODE1,1,0\n2,NODE2,0,0";
//  private final static String LINEREGEX = "(?<id>\\d+),(?<name>\\w+),(?<active>[01]),(?<predecessor>[\\d+|(null)])";

private final static String DEMOINPUT = "0\n1\n2";
private final static String LINEREGEX = "(?<id>\\d+)";

private final static Pattern LINEPATTERN = Pattern.compile(LINEREGEX);

private ElementComponent root = null;
private String input;

public StringInputTransformer() {
    input = DEMOINPUT;
    map();
}

private void map() {
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)) {
        sc.useDelimiter(",\\n");
        while (sc.hasNext(LINEPATTERN)) {
            String nextLine = sc.next(LINEREGEX);
            Matcher matcher = LINEPATTERN.matcher(nextLine);

            int id = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("id"));
            String name = matcher.group("name");
            String activeString = matcher.group("active");
            String preId = matcher.group("predecessor");

            Boolean active = "1".equals(activeString) ? true : false;
            ElementComponent element = new ElementComponent(id, name, active);
            if ("null".equals(preId)) {
                this.root = element;
            } else {
                handleNonRoot(element);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any special reason to implement a csv reader yourself? You can find many 3rd parties that do that quite efficiently

Comment: I thought of that, but than again I thought this would be a good opportunity for training regex. Which as you can see is indeed necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [\d+|(null)] does not do what you think it does

You were almost there. Here is the regex you need:

```
(?<id>\d+),(?<name>\w+),(?<active>[01]),(?<predecessor>\d+|null)
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/47), look at the group captures **in the right-hand pane**.

**Explanation**

- The main difference is the final group: `(?<predecessor>\d+|null)`
- What you had with `[\d+|(null)]` is a character class that matches one character that is either a digit, or a character that is one of those: `|`, `(`, `n`, `u`, `l` or `)`
- In contrast, `\d+|null` matches either a digit or the string `null`, which was your intent

To iterate through the groups, you can do something like:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<id>\\d+),(?<name>\\w+),(?<active>[01]),(?<predecessor>\\d+|null)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(yourString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // do something with regexMatcher.group("id")
        // do something with regexMatcher.group("name")
        // do something with regexMatcher.group("active")
        // do something with regexMatcher.group("predecessor")
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much for you explanation. You really helped me understanding how to use regex and how to iterate over multiple matches :)